# increment symbol for loop

Tags: java

I am creating a method that asks me for a number, and I would print out that number in asterisks. For example, if I input the number 4 this should print out:

```
*

**

***

****
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your number ");
        int number = in.nextInt();
        String numbah = Integer.toString(number);
        String substring = numbah.substring(0);


        if(number < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Bye bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < number; i ++)
        {
            System.out.println("*");
        }
    }
}
```

I am just having trouble incrementing the symbol by every line.

Comment: Try a nested loop and `System.out.print`

Comment: Define the variable before the loop `String asterisks = "*";`, and then inside loop before printing do `asterisks += "*";`, and print `asterisks` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or the simpler version:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= number; i ++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Adding inner join

Answer (score 0):

try to use repeat from java 11

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your number ");
        int number = in.nextInt();
        String numbah = Integer.toString(number);
        String substring = numbah.substring(0);


        if(number < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Bye bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < number; i ++)
        {
        System.out.println("*".repeat(i));
        }
    }
 }
```

Or from java 1.5+

```
 System.out.println(new String(new char[i]).replace("\0","*");
```

As others say you can create a String variable and concatenate an * at each for cycle

Answer (score 0):

Java 11 allows repeat method..

```
for(int i = 1; i < =number; i ++). {
           System.out.println("*".repeat(i));
      }
```